# Is it possible to use both WITH and CURSOR method in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how to use both with and cursor methods?

something like this:

```
      $chats = Items::with('users')->cursor()->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->id > 100;
        });
```

but this does not return users, like there is no with method.

Comment: You wouldn't use `cursor()` or `filter()` here; you'd simply do `->where('id', '>', 100)->get();`, and you'd have the correct result. If `id` is supposed to be `users.id`, then you'd have to do a `whereHas()`, but same idea.

Comment: but this is just a sample, I don't want to use $item->id > 100 here. I want to explode a column and do some actions on it inside filter method.

Comment: `filter()` is useful when you've already queried the database and want to refine what was returned. You can use `whereHas()` to query directly against whatever tables, which is much more efficient than loading every record into PHP's memory and doing filtering on that. If you want a better answer though, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70085776/edit) with what you're trying to do specifically.